# What does asyncio.test_utils.run_briefly exactly do?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio

As I know `asyncio.test_utils` is not documented on purpose since it is for private usage(refer this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue25073)).

However, I want to know what `asyncio.test_utils.run_briefly` dose.

For example, in here, could you explain?

```
def test_gather_shield(self):
        child1 = asyncio.Future(loop=self.loop)
        child2 = asyncio.Future(loop=self.loop)
        inner1 = asyncio.shield(child1, loop=self.loop)
        inner2 = asyncio.shield(child2, loop=self.loop)
        parent = asyncio.gather(inner1, inner2, loop=self.loop)
        test_utils.run_briefly(self.loop)
        parent.cancel()
        # This should cancel inner1 and inner2 but bot child1 and child2.
        test_utils.run_briefly(self.loop)
        self.assertIsInstance(parent.exception(), asyncio.CancelledError)
        self.assertTrue(inner1.cancelled())
        self.assertTrue(inner2.cancelled())
        child1.set_result(1)
        child2.set_result(2)
        test_utils.run_briefly(self.loop)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper makes the single event loop iteration.
It gives `asyncio` a chance to perform all pending activities like `loop.call_soon()` etc.

The rough equivalent is `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0))`.